# Google sheets: Specify a specific active tab when sharing

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a Google spreadsheets document that has about 5 sheet tabs. I need to share this document so that it appears on 5 different html pages (one for each tab). I want each html page to have a different active tab enabled when the page is loaded. Is this possible?

For example, here is the main page where the sheet appears:

http://streambuzz.net/streaming-tv-local-channels/

And if you look on the right side of the page there are 4 links each labeled "Chart: ". I want each of these links to point to this same spreadsheet but have a different active tab enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer**: After a bit more research I've discovered that you can specify the tab ID by appending the sharing URL like so:

```
#gid=1892247629
```

Where "gid" is the same as appears in the browser's URL address bar when you toggle the tab active on your spreadsheet from the Google sheets interface.

So, before the change my iframe code was:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/.../edit?usp=sharing&amp;rm=minimal"></iframe>
```

And after the change it becomes (look at the end of the src attribute):

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/.../edit?usp=sharing&amp;rm=minimal#gid=1892247629"></iframe>
```